# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

This is my component that create a checkbox input style. **Everything is running as right**, but there's this error message and I don't know why.

'Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.'

Stackoverflow require me to post more comments before submit this question, but I really haven't more information to set here... So I'll post with this question the version of what I'm using aside it.

React Version: React v16.8.3

React DOM version: React v16.8.3

Babel: https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js

```
    /* global ReactDOM, React */

    class Switch3dPermissao extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { checked: props.defaultChecked };
      }

      toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
          checked: !this.state.checked
        })
      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div>
            <label className={'mr-3 switch switch-3d switch-'+this.props.type}>
              <input type="hidden" name={this.props.id} value={this.props.offvalue} />
              <input
                id={this.props.id}
                name={this.props.id}
                value={this.props.value}
                className="switch-input"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={ this.state.checked ? true : false }
                onChange={ this.toggle }
              />
              <span className="switch-label"></span>
              <span className="switch-handle"></span>
            </label>
            <label htmlFor={ this.props.id } className="cursor-pointer" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}></label>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    // Elementos com esta classe
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-3d-permissao');

    for (var i in els) {

      var element = els[i];

      // Is default checked?
      var isChecked = false;
      var value = '1';
      if (element.attributes !== undefined) {

        if (element.attributes.checked !== undefined) {
          isChecked = true;
        }

        if (element.attributes.value !== undefined) {
          value = element.attributes.value.textContent;
        }
      }

      var id = null;
      var type = 'danger';
      var offvalue = '0';
      if (element.dataset !== undefined) {

        // data-id (The form checkbox id)
        if (element.dataset.id !== undefined) {
          id = element.dataset.id;
        }

        // data-type warning | danger | primary | info | success
        if (element.dataset.type !== undefined) {
          type = element.dataset.type;
        }

        // Valor para quando o checkbox nao esta checado
        if (element.dataset.offvalue !== undefined) {
          offvalue = element.dataset.offvalue;
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<Switch3dPermissao id={id} type={type} html={element.innerHTML} defaultChecked={isChecked} value={value} offvalue={offvalue} />, element)
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I think you are mixing react and non-react way of doing things. React is dealing with virtual DOM and re-renders elements on state change but you are manipulating DOM directly when you use getElementsByClassName which is not a correct approach.

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding attributes directly over elements? You can save these in state.

Comment: I get element attributes from html so when someone needs to use my code can just pass the attributes values to create the element as needed. What would be the 'right' way to do it?

Comment: You can pass them as props. Suppose you are creating a bootstrap button then you want to change the color of the button, you can have a prop as 'variant' and then you can pass 'success' or 'danger'. You can also change these in state and button re-renders accordingly. As a general rule of thumb, you usually need to avoid direct DOM manipulation in React apps

Comment: Can you send me some example about it?

Comment: Sure, give me few mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on it. Is needed to check if the element on FOR loop is a DOM element, if not continue to the next.

```
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-3d-permissao');

  for (var i in els) {
    var element = els[i];

    // Check if it is an object
    if (typeof element !== 'object') {
      continue;
    }

    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the use `for..in` for iterating over a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). The `for..in` loop also iterates over the non enumerable properties of the object including length which gives you the error that Target Container is not a DOM element.

To fix this, you can use `for..of` loop to loop only own it's own properties.

```js
/* global ReactDOM, React */

class Switch3dPermissao extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: props.defaultChecked };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <label className={'mr-3 switch switch-3d switch-'+this.props.type}>
          <input type="hidden" name={this.props.id} value={this.props.offvalue} />
          <input
            id={this.props.id}
            name={this.props.id}
            value={this.props.value}
            className="switch-input"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={ this.state.checked ? true : false }
            onChange={ this.toggle }
          />
          <span className="switch-label"></span>
          <span className="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={ this.props.id } className="cursor-pointer" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}></label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Elementos com esta classe
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-3d-permissao');

for (var element of els) {


  // Is default checked?
  var isChecked = false;
  var value = '1';
  if (element.attributes !== undefined) {

    if (element.attributes.checked !== undefined) {
      isChecked = true;
    }

    if (element.attributes.value !== undefined) {
      value = element.attributes.value.textContent;
    }
  }

  var id = null;
  var type = 'danger';
  var offvalue = '0';
  if (element.dataset !== undefined) {

    // data-id (The form checkbox id)
    if (element.dataset.id !== undefined) {
      id = element.dataset.id;
    }

    // data-type warning | danger | primary | info | success
    if (element.dataset.type !== undefined) {
      type = element.dataset.type;
    }

    // Valor para quando o checkbox nao esta checado
    if (element.dataset.offvalue !== undefined) {
      offvalue = element.dataset.offvalue;
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Switch3dPermissao id={id} type={type} html={element.innerHTML} defaultChecked={isChecked} value={value} offvalue={offvalue} />, element)
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div class="switch-3d-permissao" data-id="status" checked>Pode fazer login no sistema?</div>
```

See [methods of iteration docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example)

Comment: Actually, it's very weird but this 'of' is not on my code... =/
I guess that the 'code snippet' did it... õ.O

I'll try to fix it

Comment: @MarcoA.Braghim Sorry, my mistake. The description got reversed. Edited to fix that now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example to show how you can change style from state.

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: true,
      color: 'success'
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.checked

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      color: value ? 'success' : 'danger'
    });
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Test:
          <input
            name="test"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.test}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <ReactBootstrap.Button className='ml-3' variant={this.state.color}>Test</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Humm thanks a lot for it, will be very useful for sure!

But my project is mixed with jQuery so I have no a 'root' div or something like that, let me explain what is my porpose.

Comment: I have a common project with html, php, css, js, jquery, and everything you know, it is a free bootstrap template... I wanna to apply react in my life step by step because of due date of the project to be finished.

Comment: So I'm creating little independent components to be used separatelly and repeatedly as needed. On the HTML I wanna to be able to point how the element need to be rendered by the component so:

<div class="comp" data-type="success" />
<div class="comp" data-type="danger" />

Comment: So will not be necessary to change the JS file component to make it. I have this difficult to understand how to do it because it's kind a new world for me.

Maybe I miss understood what you mean and if it is the case please let me know.

Comment: As I said you need to avoid using direct DOM manipulation in React application. React will re-render your page once state is changed. You can totally avoid using jQuery in your case. As you see, it's very easy to change element styles via state.This approach can be extended for other properties. If you want to incrementally move you app to React I suggest doing this on a page by page basis rather than changing a part of a page. This helps you think in how React works and rebuild your page. Then gradually you can use your component on other pages as well.

Comment: Right, I think now it's more clear on how it must works @Hamed, thanks a lot! 

However it sadly doesn't fix my question. The error persists and I have no Idea of why. In other components it is not happening..